# Module Isomorphisms of Maximal Orders

Tags: ring-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, algebras, module-isomorphism

I have been reading the paper [Steinitz classes of central simple algebras](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/125/4/82986/steinitz-classes-of-central-simple-algebras) and they make the following claim, just above Corollary 3.2: 
Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a central simple algebra over $K$ and suppose $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ are maximal orders of $\mathcal{A}$. Then $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ are isomorphic as $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules.
Could someone provide a proof of this fact?